# Tracking payment status in react native webview

Tags: react-native, websocket, paypal, react-native-webview

I have a React Native app where i'm using sandbox rest api to complete paypal payment with the help of `react-native-webview`. This is successfully redirecting me to paypal checkout page and doing the payment. But i need to take user to the previous screen of app after successfull payment. I need to know if the transaction is successfull or not. Can i do that with websocket? If so, how can i do that?

Comment: Did you get any solution of this question?

Answer (score 1):

```
 onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
          console.log("navState.url ", navState)

          if (navState.url === "your success url") {
            // navigation.navigate('Home');
           

          } else if (navState.url === 'your cancel url') {
            // navigation.goBack();
          }

        }}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deeplink to get back to the app. But as far as being notified, if the transaction is completing without a capture API call from you, then a webhook to your public web server (yes it must be a server, not native app) will work best for a guaranteed notification, since the return is *not* guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, it is completing without a capture API. Also i don't know how to get response from paypal server in webview.